# VSCode - Customize imports organization

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Our project has agreed upon a `checkstyle` which defines the expected order of the imports

```
(..)
     <module name="CustomImportOrder">
        <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
        <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="true"/>
        <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="STATIC###STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE###THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE###SAME_PACKAGE(3)"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="IMPORT, STATIC_IMPORT, PACKAGE_DEF"/>
     </module>
(..)
```

I understand VSCode does not support getting the order from the checkstyle.xml files but it allows (through Language support for Java ™ for Visual Studio Code plugin) for the Organize Imports order to be customized by the defining it with the property `"java.completion.importOrder"`.

While attempting to replicate the order in the checkstyle, I've tried several approaches all of them using the `Organize Imports` function available. The one that came closer was:

```
"java.completion.importOrder": [
  "#",
  "java", 
  "javax",
  "",
  "com,org",
  "com.myProject"
],
```

But it still divides the `java.*` group from the `javax.*`.

With the above setting I get:

```
package (...)

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

import com.company.AddIssueRequest;
import com.company.AddIssueResponse;
import org.lombok;
import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessage;
import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessageFactory;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceMessageCallback;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;

import com.myProject.exception.MethodNotImplementedException;

class (...)
```

And I wanted it group java and javax imports as part of the same group like the example below.

```
package (...)

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

import com.company.AddIssueRequest;
import com.company.AddIssueResponse;
import org.lombok;
import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessage;
import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessageFactory;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceMessageCallback;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;

import com.myProject.exception.MethodNotImplementedException;

class (...)
```

Is that possible?

I've also tried to set both prefixed in the same item group, like it was done for `com` and `org` (see below) but is seems to not work the same way.

```
"java.completion.importOrder": [
  "#",
  "java,javax",
  "",
  "com,org",
  "com.myProject"
],
```

With this configuration the `java` and `javax` import groups are bundled together in the same json array element like the `"com,org"` import group below. I also tried using regular expressions and it also did not work.

Comment: What operation do you use to sort? In addition, the two sorts in your questions are not different.  Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm using the `Organize Imports` function (I'll update the question to include that information). Regarding the second remark, you are right.  I've updated the expected result part. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible example. `Organize Imports` will remove unused imports.